Using OpenJML with Classes that use java.awt Classes
I am trying to verify the example file (ColorConverter.java) described below, which makes use of java.awt.color.ColorSpace as follows.
`import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
/**

A class to convert RGB colors to the XYZ color model.
*/
public class ColorConverter {
/**

Converts an RGB color to the XYZ color model.


@param r the red component, between 0 and 255 inclusive.

@param g the green component, between 0 and 255 inclusive.

@param b the blue component, between 0 and 255 inclusive.

@return a float array containing the XYZ values.

@throws IllegalArgumentException if any color component is out of range.
/
/@ requires r >= 0 && r <= 255;
@ requires g >= 0 && g <= 255;
@ requires b >= 0 && b <= 255;
@ ensures \result.length == 3;
@ ensures \result[0] >= 0 && \result[1] >= 0 && \result[2] >= 0;
@*/
public static float[] convertRGBtoXYZ(int r, int g, int b) {
if (r < 0 || r > 255 || g < 0 || g > 255 || b < 0 || b > 255) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("RGB values must be between 0 and 255.");
}
ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
float[] rgb = new float[]{r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f};
return cs.toCIEXYZ(rgb);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
// Test the method
float[] xyz = convertRGBtoXYZ(255, 0, 0);
System.out.println("XYZ: " + xyz[0] + ", " + xyz[1] + ", " + xyz[2]);
}
}`


I have tried using the following commands in the directory where the file is located:
openjml --esc ColorConverter.java
and
openjml --esc --add-modules java.desktop ColorConverter.java
However, in both cases I have the same error:
/home/marcel/OpenJML/specs/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.jml:3: warning: Creating new package in unnamed module: java.awt.color package java.awt.color; ^ /home/marcel/OpenJML/specs/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.jml:7: error: There is no binary class to match this Java declaration in the specification file: java.awt.color.ColorSpace public abstract class ColorSpace extends Object implements java.io.Serializable { ^ 1 error 1 warning
Can anyone help me here?
I have tried using the following commands in the directory where the file is located:
openjml --esc ColorConverter.java
and
openjml --esc --add-modules java.desktop ColorConverter.java
However, in both cases I have the same error:
/home/marcel/OpenJML/specs/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.jml:3: warning: Creating new package in unnamed module: java.awt.color package java.awt.color; ^ /home/marcel/OpenJML/specs/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.jml:7: error: There is no binary class to match this Java declaration in the specification file: java.awt.color.ColorSpace public abstract class ColorSpace extends Object implements java.io.Serializable { ^ 1 error 1 warning
